# Можно ли использовать объекты не через интерфейс и не нарушить OOD

Tags: java, solid

Если объект класса (основного в файле) не имеет интерфейса и используется на прямую как часть состояния другого объекта, можно ли сказать что это 100% нарушает OOD в частности Dependency Inversion Principle? Просто иногда появляются мысли что некоторым объектам вроде и не нужен интерфейс... Или это от "лукавого"?

Comment: Если объект сам себе интерфейс, то и зачем ему отдельный? Ну и не стоит забывать, что догмы - зло

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть много принципов проектирования. Всегда желательно придерживаться необходимой достаточности и соблюдение в обязательном порядке всех шаблонов и принципов - лишнее усложнение.
Есть принцип KISS, которым следует пользоваться при выборе остальных применяемых методов.

Если есть обслуживающий класс, никак не влияющий на остальной код приложения, кроме как помощи в работе основного класса, то не проще ли его сделать innrer классом? Что бы и доступа к нему не было.

PS Понятие "интерфейс" это абстракция, которая мало что общего имеет с объявлением класса *interface* в java. Интерфейс - это протокол общения, то какие данные и в каком формате может объект принимать и в в каком формате возвращать.

Comment: _PS Понятие "интерфейс" это абстракция, которая мало что общего имеет с объявлением класса interface в java. Интерфейс - это протокол общения, то какие данные и в каком формате может объект принимать и в в каком формате возвращать._ ну в классе interface в java только и можно что в каком формате может объект принимать и в в каком формате возвращать данные... Как же они не имеют общего а что они тогда имеют различного? Если имеют...